# How to avoid pagination reset while sorting datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am having a simple `jquery-datatable` which allows basic `sorting` and `pagination` functionality. Consider below `data-tables` snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rendering engine</th>
      <th>Browser</th>
      <th>Platform(s)</th>
      <th>Engine version</th>
      <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+</td>
      <td> 4</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
      <td>Win 95+</td>
      <td>5.5</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
      <td>Win 98+</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
      <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
      <td>Win XP</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
      <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
      <td>1.7</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
      <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
      <td>1.8</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
      <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
      <td>1.8</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
      <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
      <td>1.9</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Camino 1.0</td>
      <td>OSX.2+</td>
      <td>1.8</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Camino 1.5</td>
      <td>OSX.3+</td>
      <td>1.8</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
      <td>1.7</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
      <td>Win 98SE+</td>
      <td>1.7</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
      <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
      <td>1.8</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>1.4</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>1.6</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
      <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>1.7</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
      <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>1.8</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
      <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
      <td>1.8</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gecko</td>
      <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
      <td>Gnome</td>
      <td>1.8</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Webkit</td>
      <td>Safari 1.2</td>
      <td>OSX.3</td>
      <td>125.5</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Webkit</td>
      <td>Safari 1.3</td>
      <td>OSX.3</td>
      <td>312.8</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Webkit</td>
      <td>Safari 2.0</td>
      <td>OSX.4+</td>
      <td>419.3</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Webkit</td>
      <td>Safari 3.0</td>
      <td>OSX.4+</td>
      <td>522.1</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Webkit</td>
      <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
      <td>OSX.4+</td>
      <td>420</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Webkit</td>
      <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
      <td>iPod</td>
      <td>420.1</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Webkit</td>
      <td>S60</td>
      <td>S60</td>
      <td>413</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Opera 7.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Opera 7.5</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Opera 8.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Opera 8.5</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Opera 9.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Opera 9.2</td>
      <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Opera 9.5</td>
      <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Opera for Wii</td>
      <td>Wii</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Nokia N800</td>
      <td>N800</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Presto</td>
      <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
      <td>Nintendo DS</td>
      <td>8.5</td>
      <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KHTML</td>
      <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
      <td>KDE 3.1</td>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KHTML</td>
      <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
      <td>KDE 3.3</td>
      <td>3.3</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KHTML</td>
      <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
      <td>KDE 3.5</td>
      <td>3.5</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tasman</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
      <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tasman</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
      <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tasman</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
      <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
      <td>Embedded devices</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
      <td>Embedded devices</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
      <td>Embedded devices</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td>Links</td>
      <td>Text only</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td>Lynx</td>
      <td>Text only</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td>IE Mobile</td>
      <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td>PSP browser</td>
      <td>PSP</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Other browsers</td>
      <td>All others</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>U</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So if you see the functionality, whenever you `paginate` to other pages and click **column sorting**, it actually resets the `pagination`.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there anyway to overcome this?

Went through various other Posts in SO but none were regarding resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle and share the link of that fiddle?

Comment: yes this is expected behaviour because when sorting happen you need to see what first record coming after sorting.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I have added snippet instead of jsfiddle, since it is highly preferable in SO..

Comment: @AlivetoDie.. Makes sense.. So no workaround for this problem right?

Comment: @AlivetoDie you are right, I am also seeing the same behavior here: https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/23/

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21001/how-to-keep-current-page-after-sorting

Comment: Ok.. Then I guess its not at all possible to achieve this.. @AlivetoDie could you please add that as answer with the link you posted in your last comment?

Comment: Let someone in future not create same question, if at all, and also the question is basically, is it possibly or not.. So I think that would be a meaningful answer.. @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the communication on the thread:- https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21001/how-to-keep-current-page-after-sorting

The findings are:-

If you mean the click on the header to trigger sort, then yes, that will always jump you back to the first page, there is no way around that without modifying DataTables, or applying your own sort / click listener to the header elements.

***So basically it's not possible by-default(means datatables doesn't provide this feature).***

You can raise a question to [datatables Site](https://datatables.net/) and ask them to do this and added it as an update to there existing library.

May be they will do it.

Comment: I think they are not gonna do it as it doesn't make sense in many cases as discussed in the thread.. So I would rather satisfy myself with those explanation and tell the same to my clients.. :)

Comment: you can try to raise question because it's seems new functionality. Also `applying your own sort / click listener to the header elements. and on that click try to redraw table with page number and your own sorting`. BTW i don't know how to do that actually too.):)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, we are on similar issue. Did you find any alternative to implement this?