# Pagination in jquery with asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a report application where are applying pagination for it and have functionality for download. suppose say we are in 4 page of that table and when we click on the download button it will pop up a message stating not able to download and then it will get set to 1 page.

How to set the page for the current page only(example 4th page).

Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#GenerateQuote').DataTable({
           lengthMenu: [
                [05, 10, -1],
                [05, 10, "All"]
            ],
            responsive: {
                details: {
                    renderer: function (api, rowIdx, columns) {
                        var data = $.map(columns, function (col, i) {
                            debugger;
                            return col.hidden ?
                                '<tr data-dt-row="' + col.rowIndex + '" data-dt-column="' + col.columnIndex + '">' +
                                '<td>' + col.title + ':' + '</td> ' +
                                '<td>' + col.data + '</td>' +
                                '</tr>' :
                                '';
                        }).join('');

                        return data ?
                            $('<table/>').append(data) :
                            false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

UI Design:
[image]

Pop Message code:

[image]

Comment: None of the posted code gives any clue as to how this works. I guess the download button is one of those PDF icons in the screenshot? What is the link behind that? Does it _always_ say you are unable to download? where is the code that shows that message?

Comment: yes nick that draw button is for downloading and if that download doesn't have anything then it will pop up a message from code behind(asp.net C#). once we click OK on the pop up it will get set to 1 from 4.

Comment: is that a expected behavior? i just gone through this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360171/how-to-avoid-pagination-reset-while-sorting-datatables

Comment: I've never used Datatable but it looks like I should. Normally I can google and skip through and understand it but not in this case. Do you know how the popup message is created? You need to change it so that it doesn't "post back" there is nothing in the code you provided that pops up a message so it must be part of the datagrid code or it must be part of the controller method.

Comment: Nick i have added the code which throws the message. but the functionality of changing the pagination written in jquery.